# Can you save a whole java project in oracle db express edition?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to save a java project into my oracle db express edition, as it haves dependencies and I can not save just the Main class with `CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED ... AS`
Is there any way to save the project in order to access one of the main's class methods from pl/sql later on?

I've tried to save it as a directory on my db, but I don't really know how to call the method then.

Comment: Package your project in a Jar file and then use the method in the linked duplicate.